# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Subscribe to topics and receive messages in php

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

Would it be possible with server side code to subscribe to topics and receive messages in php?

I have some code that I would like to run whenever a message is send.

Answer (score -1):

There is no client to **receive** Firebase Cloud Messaging data in PHP. You will have to find another way to trigger that PHP code when you also send the FCM message.

Comment: If its not possible to do from php itself, what way could I use to trigger my server side code?
With a different language like java?

Comment: That depends. You say you want to run some code when you **send** an FCM message. How about having the code that send the message, also call to you PHP page?

Comment: I'm sadly not the one sending the message. I want to run some code on the basis of messages normally send to a mobile app.

Comment: As said: there is no client for receiving those messages in PHP. The best I can think of is writing a small client app (in Android, iOS or Web) that subscribes to the topic, and calling your PHP endpoint from within that code.